# Grep file in GVIM on Windows

Tags: windows, vim, grep

On Linux, I sometimes see a list of all the lines which match a term with this handy command:

```
:! grep -n "term" %
```

However, I am now stuck on a Windows XP SP3 machine which lacks grep! Is there a way to get this list from within VIM itself, or using some other Windows tool via `:!`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`:g`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:g).

```
:g/term

:g/term/p
```

(Trivia: [*grep* was named](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/G/grep.html) after the same `g/re/p` command in the `ed` editor, where *re* stands for "regular expression". The `p` suffix is optional, and is an abbrev for [`:print`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:p).)

To also display line numbers, either add [`:nu`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:nu):

```
:g/term/nu
```

or just enable [`'number'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'number') with `:set number`.

---

As an alternative to `grep`, Windows comes with tools [`find`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/find.mspx?mfr=true) and [`findstr`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true) that have the same basic functions.

```
:! find "term" %

:! findstr term %
```

Comment: By all means, stick with `:g`. `find` and `findstr` seem to be specifically engineered to trip up the grep-familiar.

Comment: Terrific, thank you! I knew that there had to be a VIM-internal command!